# Splitting a string between two words

Tags: python, regex, split, delimiter

The following string

```
text = 'FortyGigE1/0/53\r\nCurrent state: DOWN\r\nLine protocol state: DOWN\r\n\r\nFortyGigE1/0/54\r\nCurrent state: DOWN\r\nLine protocol state: DOWN\r\n\r\n'
```

should be split into this:

```
output = [
    'FortyGigE1/0/53\r\nCurrent state: DOWN\r\nLine protocol state: DOWN\r\n\r\n',
    'FortyGigE1/0/54\r\nCurrent state: DOWN\r\nLine protocol state: DOWN\r\n\r\n'
]
```

The delimiters should not be deleted after the splitting.

```
delimiters = '(GigabitEthernet\d*/\d*/\d*\s.*|FortyGigE\d*/\d*/\d*\s.*)'
```

I tried to do this:

```
output = re.split(delimiters, text)
```

But my output will be this, with many more splits than I expected:

```
['',
 'FortyGigE1/0/53\r', '\nCurrent state: DOWN\r\nLine protocol state: DOWN\r\n\r\n',
 'FortyGigE1/0/54\r', '\nCurrent state: DOWN\r\nLine protocol state: DOWN\r\n\r\n']
```

Comment: It seems you want to split the string at blank lines, i.e. two consectutive line breaks, why don't you simply use `text.split('\r\n\r\n')`?

Comment: The string "text" are interface statistics of network switches, which are saved in a (long) file. I want to separate this file in a List of the interfaces. So each element of this List starts with a Keyword "GigbitEthernet" or "FortyGigE" and also ends with the same Keyword. Everything between the Keyword plus the first Keyword is one interface.

Comment: Yes. Did you try what I suggested? Is there a reason why this doesn't work?

Comment: `text.split('\r\n\r\n')[:-1]`?

Comment: I have to test your suggestion “ text.split('\r\n\r\n')[:-1]? ” and will also try the suggestion from the user “dawg“. I’ve seen that the output from different switch or maybe from different terminal emulators have different white spaces. Some outputs (files) have only one “\n” as a separator, other a combination or mix of “\r\n”.

Answer (score 0):

At least with your example, you can do:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<=DOWN\r\n\r\n)(?=FortyGigE)', text)
['FortyGigE1/0/53\r\nCurrent state: DOWN\r\nLine protocol state: DOWN\r\n\r\n',
 'FortyGigE1/0/54\r\nCurrent state: DOWN\r\nLine protocol state: DOWN\r\n\r\n']
```

Comparing to your stated desired output:

```
>>> output==re.split(r'(?<=DOWN\r\n\r\n)(?=FortyGigE)', text)
True
```

It works by using a zero width lookback `(?<=DOWN\r\n\r\n)` and a zero width lookahead `(?=FortyGigE)` as the point to split.

[Here is a regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZiaU5n/1/); the `\r` are removed since they are not supported on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

your tip gave me the solution for my problem. Here the excerpt of my script:

```
f = open(file, "r")
content = f.read()
f.close()
#
# This deliminator is only an example. The interface names are much longer
deliminators = r'(?=\nBridge-Aggregation|\nHundredGigE|\nFortyGigE|\nTen-GigabitEthernet)'
#
dev_interfaces = re.split(deliminators, content)
max_interfaces = len(dev_interfaces)
# Delete the beginning Linefeed (\n) of each interface
dev_interfaces[index] = dev_interfaces[index].lstrip('\n')
```